# Custom domain won't retain path with Apache redirect on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, apache, .htaccess, redirect

my .htaccess works perfectly when testing locally, when I deploy to azure app service, and trying from customdomain.com/foo/content/bar.. --> newdomain.com, it wont retain path, if I use the azure's app service domain name which usually is: something-some-prod.azurewebsites.com the above works perfectly again with the path taken over.

.htaccess, example:

```
RewriteRule "^/?foo/foo/content/bar/content2/?$" "https://www.newdomain.com/foo/foo/" [L,R=301,NE]
```

- the above content doesnt exist anyomre on the old domain, and i want to retain the foo/foo part, which is why i force this one.

my other rule, which is at the end:

```
RewriteRule "^/?(.*)" "https://www.newdomain.com/$1" [L,R=301,NE]
```

Not sure whats going on, anyone?

UPD:
This is what i have on the newdomain host, .htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine On

# Handle URL Canonicalization 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.old-domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^new-domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.new-domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]


# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: _"my other rule, which is at the end"_ - so are you saying, what you redirect via that, works as intended in all cases - and only the one specific case you are trying to handle via the other rule, does not?

Comment: @CBroe no, both wont work. All im getting is a redirect to newdomain.com, no matter the path. Although if I do this: olddomain.com/?foobar --> newdomain.com/?foobar , query gets taken over.

Comment: If either of these rules applies, then I don't see what about this should not work as intended. And if they didn't - then the question would be, _what_ is redirecting you to the new domain in the first place then ...? Maybe the redirect _is_ happening - but then newdomain itself is redirecting to its root afterwards, for some reason?

Comment: @CBroe Absolutely, it works, but not as intended. I updated it with the newdomain .htaccess file. I think the first URL Canonicalization Rule for the old domain should be removed, of which I dont think it would solve my problem, but its no necessary here anymore.

Comment: If you don't have old and new domain pointing to the same folder on the same webspace, then it makes no sense to have that in there in the first place - a request for `old-domain.com` would never reach this in the first place. (And if you do have them both pointing there, then it would still make rather little sense to send the user from `old-domain.com` to `www.old-domain.com` first, only to then redirect them to `www.new-domain.com` again.)

Comment: Both the new domain and old domain redirect runs from the same Azure resource group, but separate WebbApp services.

Comment: Agree, it was left there, as it shouldnt, I just recently got my hands on this.

Comment: Use your browser dev tools to first of all figure out, _when_ you are losing the path. Is it really `olddomain/somepathhere` -> `newdomain/`, or is it maybe `olddomain/somepathhere` -> `newdomain/somepathhere` -> `newdomain/`?

Comment: I lose the path at the first redirect, I used an online tracer, like redirect-checker.org.
What happens is i noticed, i always land on simply newdomain.com with no path, then the URL canonicalization redirects to www
`www.oldomain/path` -> `https://newdomain.com` -> `www.newdomain.com`

Comment: _"i always land on simply newdomain.com with no path, then the URL canonicalization redirects to www www.oldomain/path"_ - huh? Why would your URL canonicalization `old-domain.com` even still apply, at the point you are requesting `newdomain.com` already?

Comment: I see 2 redirects, first one is from `old to new`, then `new to new` and at the second one happens the url can. which is legitimate as is stated in the newdomain htaccess. but i already lost the path at the first one.

Comment: _"then new to new"_ - don't see how, you are redirecting from old directly to `www.new-domain.com`, so your canonicalization part for the new domain can't come into play here. So what else could be redirecting you now (if not your actually application itself, outside of any .htaccess context)? _"then new to new"_ - can you be a bit more specific? What are the actual URLs?

Comment: The azure web app service has a custom domain set which is the old domain (www.old-domain.com, old-domain.com) the only thing is deployed here is a default httpd.conf(enabled redirect mod, set the location folder for the conf files) file the a .htaccess file, all this in a container.
The new domain, which is a php website, also has a .htaccess file, as also shown above, running from a container again.
This is just for context. That here shouldnt be anything on the old domain that overwrites or messes with the apache redirect.

Comment: to be more specific:
`https://newdomain.com` -> `https://www.newdomain.com`

Comment: not to forget that the redirect works perfectly on localhost, and with the azure webapp domain name, but only the old domain name does not retain the path.

Comment: _"to be more specific: `https://newdomain.com` -> `https://www.newdomain.com`"_ - more specific on - what? Is that one of the redirects you see happening? (If so, I wouldn't know how, if from the old domain you redirected to the www version of the new one to begin with?)

Comment: Yes, its the second redirect. I might not explaining things good here:) sorry. The old domain never redirects to the www version. The www version comes from the new domain redirect (URL canon.)

Comment: So the first redirect from the old domain is not to the www version of the new one then, apparently. Can't tell if what's in your .htaccess is actually correct in that regard, with the actual domains being replace, but if it is, then you'll probably have to investigate if anything else on the old server messes with the redirect headers somehow before they get send to the client.

Comment: Hmmm, i just realized that the two web app services are running from the same service plan in azure. not sure though if this is relevant in this case yet.

Comment: `2023-10-21T07:40:53.463920713Z [Sat Oct 21 07:40:53.463762 2023] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 10:tid 124938295728952] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <IP>:31023] <IP>- - [www.old-domain.com/sid#71a176dab1c0][rid#71a1768598a0/initial] [perdir /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/] redirect to https://www.new-domain.com/ [REDIRECT/301]`
`2023-10-21T07:40:53.468438909Z <IP> - - [21/Oct/2023:07:40:53 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 237`

Comment: I enabled logging in apache server, this is the log.

Comment: Okay i think i figured this one out, the old domain SSL certificate is expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL certificate was expired on the old domain.